# .htaccess, virtual directories, and semi-complex URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm basically just trying to have a master syntax for predictable URLs. Simple URL is no problem

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteRule ^friendlyUrl/content/?$ /index.php?app=main&module=content
```

Which to my understanding looks for the url structure and allows 1 or 0 trailing "/"'s

But some parts of the website have a /urlPrefix/ to access, eg. `mysite.com/membersArea/`
and `/membersArea/` will be apart of every query there. I'm having trouble accomodating for trailing `?`s and `&`s in URLs like these.

```
RewriteRule ^secureUrl/\?(.*)$ /index.php?app=admin&$1
```

This is my attempt to handle everything from `mysite.com/secureUrl/` to `mysite.com/secureUrl/?var1=foo&var2=bar` and after many server errors *and a search*, I find myself here.

This is the most complex line I have and between you and me, I couldn't tell you exactly what's happening other than it looks for `/friendlyUrl/10DIGITKEY/(possible task)/?possiblevars=foo&var2=bar`

```
RewriteRule ^friendlyUrl/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/?([a-z]*)/?\??(.*)$ /index.php?app=main&module=web&id=$1&$2&$3
```

Htaccess has always been my weakest subject, and as a webmaster I pay the price constantly, any help would be appreciated.

Need to input the same request to the PHP file (plus ANY query with or without `?` or `&`) whether its just `/friendlyUrl/` or `/friendyUrl/?var=1`, `/friendlyUrl/&var=1`, `/friendlyUrl/var=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to keep the *query string* of your request URI to remain as is, or to be included in the rewritten URL after the rewrite process is done.

For this purpose, you use the [`QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) in your `RewriteRule` directive. So, to rewrite `/friendlyUrl/10DIGITKEY/(possible task)/?possiblevars=foo&var2=bar`, you'd have:

```
RewriteRule ^friendlyUrl/([a-z\d]{10})/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?app=main&module=web&id=$1&task=$2 [QSA]
```

Notice the `QSA` flag at the end. Also, keep in mind that I'm passing the second match (the *possible task* of your URL) as another variable (named `task`). This variable will be empty if nothing was found.

---

> #### [`QSA|qsappend`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)
>
> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of `RewriteRule` is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the **`[QSA]`** flag causes the
>   query strings to be combined.